# How to drag and drop a UITableView that can automatically expand to fill the full screen in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode8

I saw in some videos, people can just drag and drop a table view to a view and it will automatically expand to fill the full screen. How can i do that with Xcode 8.2.1?

Comment: If you use UITableViewController then your tableview automatically expand.

Comment: can you please mention any of those videos link here? (In which you've seen tableView expanding to full screen)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mON0GQBsCwo at  0:24 of the video. I just thinking whether it's because i am using more updated Xcode..

Comment: +Prabhat Pankaj But it's really not the case for my Xcode. Are you sure you are referring to all the Xcode?

Comment: @JiaLi the tutorial you are referring is using old version of Xcode. This seems not possible in current version of Xcode. For that you have to apply auto layouts to your tableview

Comment: @NileshPol i guess you are quite right

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the video is not displayed some autolayout settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing me that. But i can't do that with my Xcode 8.2.1...

Comment: @OMGHaveFun please read the question before answering. Question is not asked as `How to apply auto layout to uitableview`. Your answer is not matching to question